# Thanks for sharing your great experience!

Tags: american-english

I want to thank a person for what he taught me. How can I say him this?

> Thank you for sharing experience

Is this sentence correct? Does not it contains lexical errors?

Comment: Check out the ELL Q&A http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your sentence grammatically. The word *great* seems a bit unnecessary to me. So, I would probably reword it as follow:

> Thanks for sharing your experience with me[or us].
>
> Thanks for sharing your experience.
>
> Thank you for sharing your experience with me.
>
> Thank you for sharing your experience.